# Android - ProgressDialog is running on back of FragmentDialog

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-progressbar, bringtofront

I've used a customProgressDialog and when when I use it inside a FragmentDialog then it appears on the back of FragmentDialog, looks like it is attached  withe the activity that is calling FragmentDialog and not the FragmentDialog itself. How can i bring the ProgressDialog to front?
Note: Theme is different for CustomProgressDialog and FragmentDialog

Comment: Use a Progress Bar with some Elevation

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a lot of people have complained about that similar problem with ProgressDialog.

To work around this, I recommend that you try using a normal dialog, created with the builder and whose layout (a custom one made by you) includes the progress bar or loading (or whatever you need). This should solve your problem.

Comment: I've tried simple ProgressDiaolg as well ans having same issue.